# How to get remote IP Address of client in identity server 4

Tags: identityserver4

Is there a property in the context variable (ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext) that lets me access the IP address of the client sending the initial request for an auth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no information like that for you to grab within that context. Your only Option is to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and then you can get the request IP from the `HttpContext.Request` object.