# How i can add the calculated fields to access_token / id_token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using IdentityServer4 and I want to add the calculated fields to access_token / id_token.

An example of such a field can be the user's IP (or token binding hash), to which the token will be attached.

**Q:** How i can do this?

*Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english.*

Comment: I m sorry but i cant fully understand your question :v

Comment: @Agent_Orange sorry :). I want the identityServer to include the user's IP address, received during the login, in access_token. How i can do this?

Comment: Maybe this could help [get remote IP Address of client in identity server 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429575/how-to-get-remote-ip-address-of-client-in-identity-server-4)

Comment: Thanks for trying. But this question did not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add claims that contain the calculated fields by creating a method in your UserManager implementation.

```
public class UserManager: IUserManager
{
    ...other code here removed for simplicity

    public List<Claim> GetClaimsAsync(Models.User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();             

        claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, user.USER_ID.ToString().Trim()));

        //This next line is pseudo coded and would need to be coded.
        claims.Add(new Claim("MyCalculatedIP", MyFunctionToGetUserIP().ToString().Trim()));


        return claims;
    }

    ...other code here removed for simplicity
}
```

Call this from the class that implements the IProfileService. I named mine ProfileService.

```
/// <summary>
///  implement the interface called "IProfileService", which is used for authorization.
/// </summary>
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    IUserManager _myUserManager;
    private readonly ILogger<ProfileService> _logger;


    public ProfileService(ILogger<ProfileService> logger, IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _myUserManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {            
        var user = await _myUserManager.Find(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                             subject: user.USER_ID,
                             authenticationMethod: "custom",
                             claims: await _myUserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));
        }
        else
        {                 
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                             TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, 
                    errorDescription: "UserName or Password Incorrect.");
        }             
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Get profile called for {subject} from {client} with {claimTypes} because {caller}",
            context.Subject.GetSubjectId(),
            context.Client.ClientName,
            context.RequestedClaimTypes,
            context.Caller);

        var sub = context.Subject.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
        if (sub != null)
        {
            var user = await _myUserManager.FindByNameAsync(sub);
            var cp = getClaims(user);

            var claims = cp.Claims;                

            context.IssuedClaims = claims.ToList();
        }
    }

    private ClaimsPrincipal getClaims(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity();

        id.AddClaims(_myUserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));

        return new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by IdentityServer Middleware.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _myUserManager.FindByNameAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null;
        return;
    }
}
```

In the Startup class add the ProfileService object for Dependency Injection.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...other code here removed for simplicity

     Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

     ...other code here removed for simplicity
}
```

Helpful sources
[artile](http://www.sunilrav.com/post/How-to-Customize-Authentication-in-Identity-Server-4)